# Runtime Error 3061 VBA using Insert command

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have the following code.  I am using a form in MS Access 2010 to enter new lines into my table Nlog.  When I try to run the code, it gives me the error Run-Time error '3061': Too few parameters. Expected 1.

I can't find the error!

```
Private Sub Command128_Click()
    'add data to table
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO NLog(IDKEY, Company, CoName, State, City, AmtpdTotal, DateRec, Notified, DateNotice, AcctID, TaxType, Period, NoticeReason, Resolution, TaxDue, Intdue, PenDue, Dateres, Amtpdint, amtpdpen, amtpdtax, Assigned, subAssgn, Resolved) " & _
        " VALUES(" & Me.TxtIDKEY & ",'" & Me.Company & "','" & Me.CoName & "','" & _
        Me.State & "','" & Me.City & "','" & Me.TxtAmtpdTotal & "','" & _
        Me.DateRec & "','" & Me.Notified & "','" & _
        Me.DateNotice & "','" & Me.AcctID & "','" & Me.TaxType & "','" & Me.Period & "','" & _
        Me.NoticeReason & "','" & Me.Resolution & "','" & Me.TaxDue & "','" & Me.IntDue & "','" & Me.PenDue & "','" & _
        Me.DateRes & "','" & Me.AmtPdInt & "','" & Me.AmtpdPen & "','" & Me.AmtpdTax & "','" & _
        Me.Assigned & "','" & Me.txtsubass & "','" & Me.Resolved & "')", dbFailOnError 
MsgBox ("Entry Added")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a string variable to hold the `INSERT` statement.  That allows you to `Debug.Print` the string so you can inspect the actual statement your code created.  And you can `Execute` the string.

```vb
Dim strInsert As String
strInsert = "INSERT INTO NLog(IDKEY, Company, CoName, State, City, AmtpdTotal, DateRec, Notified, DateNotice, AcctID, TaxType, Period, NoticeReason, Resolution, TaxDue, Intdue, PenDue, Dateres, Amtpdint, amtpdpen, amtpdtax, Assigned, subAssgn, Resolved) " & _
    " VALUES(" & Me.TxtIDKEY & ",'" & Me.Company & "','" & Me.CoName & "','" & _
    Me.State & "','" & Me.City & "','" & Me.TxtAmtpdTotal & "','" & _
    Me.DateRec & "','" & Me.Notified & "','" & _
    Me.DateNotice & "','" & Me.AcctID & "','" & Me.TaxType & "','" & Me.Period & "','" & _
    Me.NoticeReason & "','" & Me.Resolution & "','" & Me.TaxDue & "','" & Me.IntDue & "','" & Me.PenDue & "','" & _
    Me.DateRes & "','" & Me.AmtPdInt & "','" & Me.AmtpdPen & "','" & Me.AmtpdTax & "','" & _
    Me.Assigned & "','" & Me.txtsubass & "','" & Me.Resolved & "')"
Debug.Print strInsert
CurrentDb.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError
```

You can then view the completed statement (the output from `Debug.Print`) in the Immediate window.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> will take you to the Immediate window.

If the error is not obvious, you can copy the statement text, create a new query in the query designer, switch it to SQL View, and paste in the copied statement.  When you try to run that query from the designer, Access will display a parameter dialog which asks you to supply a value for the parameter.  Notice that dialog also includes the "name" of the parameter.  Frequently the cause of this problem is a misspelled field name --- since Access can't find a field by that name, it assumes it must be a parameter instead.

Alternatively, you can use VBA code to show you the names of any parameters in your query:

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strInsert)
For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    Debug.Print prm.Name
Next
```